# add attribute to a user when loging in

Tags: django

I am using an app to be able to log in as another user from the admin: https://github.com/stochastic-technologies/django-loginas

I'd like to add a flag on the session or the user to be able to differentiate in the template that an admin is logged in as a user to avoid triggering certain things.

The app uses the [django.contrib.auth.login](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7.1/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L74) method:
https://github.com/stochastic-technologies/django-loginas/blob/master/loginas/views.py#L63

I cannot add a variable to the request.session because it is flushed in the login method so I thought I could add one on the user by doing this before the login method `setattr(user, 'loginas_from_user', request.user.pk)` but this does not work either. There is no value in the template `{{ request.user.loginas_from_user }}`.

Any idea why?
Another idea to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: is it possible to just add a javascript cookie?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work. I just thought I could add an attribute on the user that I can see in my template. I still do not understand why my attribute is not available...